# Setting the Accent Color does not work when using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I created a blank UNO Platform application and added some controls to the MainPage.xaml (ListView, Button, ComboBox and CheckBox). This is how it looks:

[image: My UWP test app]

Now I want to change the color, therfor I tried overriding the accent color in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"  />
                <!-- Place resources here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Color x:Key="SystemColorHighlightColor">#E64A19</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#E64A19</Color>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemColorControlAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}" />
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

but it did not work. How can I change the accent color?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the system colors for light and dark theme does the trick:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"  />
                <!-- Place resources here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight1">#FF0000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight2">#FF0000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight3">#FF0000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark1">#FF0000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark2">#FF0000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark3">#FF0000</Color>
       </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```